# How to rearrange a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

So for various reasons that go outside of this post, I am writing a file that transfers data from one place to another. I have some of the data held in a series of multidimensional arrays

lets pretend I have a 4 dimensional array with the following shape/dimensions:
[x, y, z, n]

How would I rearrange it into these dimensions:
[n, z, y, x]
OR
[z, y, n, z]

I am NOT looking for a short and quick answer or piece of code. I want to understand the answer so that for future I could do it on my own

My idea:
Flatten the array out with a series of nested for loops

`for n in [n, :,:,:]
    for x in [:, x, :,:]`

so on and so forth until I unravel the whole thing into a one dimensional array. But I am not sure how exactly I would get it back in the form I would like

Comment: just transpose it! you'll get the [n,z,y,x] version.

Answer (score 1):

for the horizontal flipping you only need one loop.
you need to go from the first place to the centered place, and replace each one with the same one on the opposite. for example:

```
lets say that we have an int length. and then:
for(int i=0;i<length/2;i++)
{
   switch array[i] with array[length-i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transpose:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> b = zip(*a)
>>> b
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```